# Show/Expand all kubernetes endpoints hidden behind "+1 more..."

Tags: kubernetes

It seems a silly question, but how do I expand the "+ 1 more..." from the endpoints list?

Particularly I want to see all the endpoints of a service and the following command hides some endpoints behind the "+ 1 more...".

```
   kubectl describe service <name>
```

I tried this:

```
   kubectl get endpoints -o wide
```

It still doesn't show the hidden one.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use `kubectl describe endpoints` ?

Comment: thanks rnr, actually I was wanting to find the endpoints of a service, and I have the same problem with ```kubectl describe service```. Is there a way to filter for a particular service with your command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command: `kubectl describe endpoints <endpoint name>`

For eg. the output of `kubectl get endpoints -o wide`:

```
NAME                                         ENDPOINTS                                                              AGE
traefik-dashboard                            10.52.171.114:8080,10.52.171.120:8080,10.52.171.134:8080 + 1 more...   64d
```

& the output of `kubectl describe endpoints traefik-dashboard`:

```
Name:         traefik-dashboard
Namespace:    default
Labels:       app=traefik
              chart=traefik-1.87.7
              heritage=Helm
              release=traefik
Annotations:  endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time: 2021-03-03T17:23:55Z
Subsets:
  Addresses:          10.52.171.114,10.52.171.120,10.52.171.134,10.52.171.8
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name            Port  Protocol
    ----            ----  --------
    dashboard-http  8080  TCP

Events:  <none>
```

As you can see, it lists all IP addresses in the endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting approach would be to output the json and extract the relevant fields. This is useful if you want to analyse the output after. You may want to add the namespace in case you have multiple.

Single command:

```
kubectl get endpoints -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name},{.subsets[*].addresses[*].ip}{'\n'}{end}"
```

Bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for service in `kubectl get endpoints -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name},{.subsets[*].addresses[*].ip}{'\n'}{end}"`; do
  echo $service | awk -F, {'print $1'}
  for endpoint in $(echo $services | awk -F, {'print $2'}); do
    echo $endpoint
  done
done
```